# GitLab submodule complains about AWS CloudFormation templates located in submodule

Tags: gitlab, aws-cloudformation, gitlab-ci, aws-cli

I am facing a problem with GitLab include and I'm wondering whether it's possible to do what I intent to.

I have 2 GitLab repositories:

1. `my-infrastructure`
2. `my-prod-deployment`

In `my-infrastructure` I have the YML file that defines a job with a command referencing a local file. For example in `my-infrastructure` I have the following:

A `gitlab-infrastructure.yml` template

```
image: amazon/aws-cli

variables:
  FOO: ReplaceMe

stages:
  - one

agent_ui:
  stage: microservices
  script:
    - aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name sample --template-file templates/aws-template.yml
```

and also I have a `templates/aws-template.yml` that has some cloud formation code.

Notice that the GitLab template needs access to a local file that exists in the same project `my-infrastructure`

Now in the other project `my-prod-deployment` I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` with

```
include:
  - project: mycompany/my-infrastructure
    ref: main
    file: gitlab-infrastructure.yml

variables:
  FOO: Bar
```

When I run this CI/CD pipeline I can see the `FOO` variable being properly overriden and I can see that the included job's script is executed. The problem is that I get a

```
$ aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name sample --template-file templates/aws-template.yml
Invalid template path templates/aws-template.yml
```

**This is probably because the local relative path is in `my-infrastructure`, but not in `my-prod-deployment` that file is not locally available in this project and therefore it can't be found.**

Is there any solution to this?
Maybe a way to include not only gitlab but also other files or similar?
Or maybe some kind of shortcut or link to a different repo folder?
Or maybe a way to temporary copy a remote folder to the local CI/CD pipeline execution?

*Notice that I cannot use an absolute or URL path for that script parameter since that specific tool (AWS CLI) does not allow it. Otherwise I wouldn't face this relative path issue*

---

**UPDATE 1**: I have tried a workaround with git submodules separating the gitlab template in a different project and adding `my-infrastructure` as a submodule

```
cd my-prod-deployment
git submodule add git@gitlab.com:mycompany/my-infrastructure.git
```

so that my `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this

```
include:
  - project: mycompany/my-gitlab-templates
    ref: main
    file: gitlab-infrastructure.yml

variables:
  CLOUDFORMATION_SUBMODULE: my-infrastructure
  FOO: Bar
```

and my repo has a local folder `my-infrastructure`, but I am shocked to find that it still complains about the AWS CloudFormation template path, so I've added AWS Cloud Formation tag to the question and edited it.

This is the error

```
$ aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name sample --template-file $CLOUDFORMATION_SUBMODULE/templates/aws-template.yml
Invalid template path my-infrastructure/templates/aws-template.yml
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

There is a `my-infrastructure/templates/aws-template.yml` path under my repo. It's part of the submodule. So I don't understand why this workaround does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with the git submodule approach.
I had to add 2 changes as per https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html

Add the submodule with relative path

```
git submodule add ../my-infrastructure.git
```

So that `.gitmodules` displays the relative url within the same server

```
[submodule "my-infrastructure"]
    path = my-infrastructure
    url = ../my-infrastructure.git
```

and add this variable to `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
variables:
  # submodule behavior
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```